# Bug in iOS app dealing with certain Unicode characters

Tags: bug, ios-app, rtl

[Example](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/98984/why-is-uk-passport-control-so-much-stricter-than-in-the-schengen-area#comment237627_98984):

[image: Bug Example: Paul of Osawatomie أبو عمار 14 hours ago]

The Arabic characters are displayed within the time.
The expected behaviour is that the entire user name is displayed, followed by the time.

- App Version: 1.6.6.2
- Device: iPhone 6
- OS Version: Version 10.3.3 (Build 14G60)

Comment: This only seems to apply if the one is more than 1 word. [The text looks fine when the date is yesterday](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wgpt4.jpg). (Version 1.7.0.1, iPhone 6)